# awk command to print all lines in a unix file where a pattern exists and the numerical value after the found pattern is greater than 100

Tags: awk

I have a log file which has below format.
I am having trouble writing an unix command for the below scenario:

Lines in the log

```
—---count of xyz
{  "_id" : "xyz",  "total" : 70 }
{  "_id" : "def",  "total" : 100 }
{  "_id" : "xyz",  "total" : 180 }
—Count of abcd
{  "_id" : [ "ABCD" ],  "total" : 94 }
{  "_id" : [ "EFGH" ],  "total" : 94 }
```

I am using the below command to print only the lines where total is greater than 100. But it doesn’t work as expected. 
How can we accomplish this?

```
My command is 
grep "total" abcd.log | awk '$9 > 50  {print ;}' | more
```

Expected Output :
All the lines where total exists and total > 100

```
{  "_id" : "xyz",  "total" : 180 }
```

Comment: I edited my question with expected output.Expected output is only one line. But my command prints everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field you're trying to test isn't always 9th from the start but it is always 1 from the end:

```
$ awk '/total/ && ($(NF-1) > 100)' file
{  "_id" : "xyz",  "total" : 180 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for awk but grep can be a bit simpler:

```
grep '"total" *: *[0-9]\{3,\} *}$' input
```

If total is a unique key, this should work too:

```
grep '"total" *: *[0-9]\{3,\}' input
```

These also print, for example, 011, but it can be fixed if necessary.

Comment: How is that simpler than an awk solution that just numerically tests for the value being greater than 100?

Comment: It's subjective yes, but grep is more widely known and has a simpler language.